# how to fix URL Resolve, 301 redirects in the htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm a novice and I work PHP. My professor introduced a site that gives me website problems. (woorank)
My site has a problem with 301 redirects. Look at the picture below.

[Click to see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyE4h.png)

My problem is and I want to resolve this problem in the `.htaccess` file. I knew the following code answered this but was wrong

```
// URL Resolve
if (currentUrl() == "http://example.com") {
    redirectToMainDomain();
} elseif (currentUrl() == "http://www.example.com") {
    redirectToMainDomain();
} elseif (currentUrl() == "https://example.com") {
    redirectToMainDomain();
} elseif (currentUrl() == "https://www.example.com") {
    redirectToMainDomain();
}
```

I wrote the above code on the first line of codes, but my problem was not resolved, I do something like this to apply in the `.htaccess` file.

```
if (currentUrl() == "https://www.example.com" or currentUrl() == "https://example.com" or currentUrl() == "http://example.com" or currentUrl() == "http://www.example.com") {
        header("Location: https://example.com");
        exit;
    }
if (currentUrl() == "https://www.example.com/blog/index.php" or currentUrl() == "https://example.com/blog/index.php" or currentUrl() == "http://example.com/blog/index.php" or currentUrl() == "http://www.example.com/blog/index.php") {
        header("Location: https://example.com/blog/index.php");
        exit;
    } 
// and other pages
```

Please guide

Comment: What is the problem you want to resolve? And what is a "cat file"?

Comment: Typographical mistakes * .htaccess file

Comment: Then please share more details, like an explanation of the problem you are facing and your attempts to resolve it. Writing rewrite rules is well documented, so usual problems in this field can be resolved by reading the documentation

Comment: I need a code like this: `redirect https://www.example.com and others to https:example.com and https://www.example.com/blog/index.html and others to https://example.com/blog/index.html` in the `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am the author of the question.**
You can fix this using the following code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your site URLs with or without `https` and `www` point to different locations that is why your are seeing the redirect error. You can fix this using the following code in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# rediret http and non-www to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Change `example.com` to your domain in the code above and test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: This answer was correct. But this code only worked on the home screen. I want this code to be done for all of my site pages

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/ [R=301]
```

Add this to the `.htaccess` which is located in the **root** folder of your site.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This problem solved the "WooRank". But I want to do other pages as well. Now every all CSS files are not read on my PHP page. For example, my domain begins with the `https://` but behind the address page of the files is in the form of `http://`